# Domain bidding. The seller of the domain has failed to respond

Tags: domains, dns, domain-registrar

I was trying to place a bid on domain trough sedo.com and got such response:

> We regret to inform you that the seller of the domain has failed to
>   respond to your bid in spite of our repeated reminders.
>
> If the seller does not respond within 14 days, this bid thread will be
>   considered inactive and no additional reminder emails will be sent.
>
> To prevent this, you can extend the negotiation period by making a
>   higher counter-offer

What would u do in such case?

the domain status says:

```
Status: clientDeleteProhibited
Status: clientRenewProhibited
Status: clientTransferProhibited
Status: clientUpdateProhibited
Updated Date: 30-aug-2013
Creation Date: 15-aug-2002
Expiration Date: 15-aug-2014
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it, try again with a higher bid. Otherwise, I would forget it.

You have not told use why you want the domain name. If it is important, that is something *you* have to decide. I do not play this bidding game ever. I find domain names that are available and register them. I have never had an issue with this. There are a bunch of domain name squatters out there and frankly, I feel this is an extremely sleazy practice. But not all domain names sold are from squatters. They could be just like me and you. If that is the case, then I feel this is a valid practice and maybe worth pursuing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Status: clientDeleteProhibited
Status: clientRenewProhibited
Status: clientTransferProhibited
Status: clientUpdateProhibited
Updated Date: 30-aug-2013
Creation Date: 15-aug-2002
Expiration Date: 15-aug-2014
```

That means that the domain is locked from transfer by the person who has registered it. Even if you did bid for the domain, it doesn't mean you are going to get it nor do the people who own it want to sell it.

This domain was created in 2002, which says that they may want to keep it as they have had it registered it for going on 12 years now.

I do understand that you wanted it. Also, you never gave us enough details if you have tried to contact them as if you were interested in buying the domain from them, which doesn't help nor give any idea that you wanted the domain.